# How to use my device's VID and PID inside UsbDeviceFinder function of LibUsbDotNet?

Tags: c#, winforms, usb, libusbdotnet

I am trying to use my USB device inside my C# windows form application, I have found the VID and PID of my device from device manager and they are mentioned like below:

USB\VID_1A86&PID_7523

Now inside my code I have a function named **UsbDeviceFinder** which gets two integer numbers for PID and VID.

When I use the following code I get an error message which says I should use int numbers inside this function.

```
public static UsbDeviceFinder MyUsbFinder = new UsbDeviceFinder(1A86, 7523);
```

It seems like these two numbers are in HEX format. Am I supposed to convert both of them to decimal and then pass them to the function?

Even when I convert these two numbers to Decimal I get the Device not found error. How can I fix this?

Comment: `int num = int.Parse("1A86", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);`. It expects Int32 values.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public static UsbDeviceFinder MyUsbFinder = new UsbDeviceFinder(0x1A86, 0x7523);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21172758)

Comment: I disagree with your comment.  Since he did not provide what decimal number he used, we could not tell, but I know my solution work, because it worked for me.